# How to modify this Makefile to build c and cxx files separately?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

The following Makefile was working very well for C projects, but when we encountered a directory with `.cpp` files, we found the first pattern rule is getting used for `.cpp` files.  I've tried 3 or 4 changes to get the desired effect, and I can't seem to find a way.  I'd like to know if it's possible to make any minor alteration to the rules below so that the `.cpp` files are built with `COMPILE_CXX_COMMAND`.

```
C_EXT             ?= c
CXX_EXT           ?= cpp
OBJ_EXT           ?= o

C_SRCS := \
src/RT_Socket.c \
src/products.c

CXX_SRCS := \
src/BurnedInAddress.cpp \
src/DiskID.cpp \


C_OBJ_FILES       += $(C_SRCS:.$(C_EXT)=.$(OBJ_EXT))
CXX_OBJ_FILES     += $(CXX_SRCS:.$(CXX_EXT)=.$(OBJ_EXT))


$(ARCHIVE_FILENAME) :   $(C_OBJ_FILES) $(CXX_OBJ_FILES)
    $(CREATE_ARCHIVE_COMMAND)

$(LIBRARY_FILENAME) :   $(ARCHIVE_FILENAME)
    $(CREATE_LIBRARY_COMMAND)

%.$(OBJ_EXT)        :   $(C_SRCS)
    $(COMPILE_C_COMMAND)

%.$(OBJ_EXT)        :   $(CXX_SRCS)
    $(COMPILE_CXX_COMMAND)
```

EDIT:
I want to add that I tried replacing the pattern targets with the list of `OBJ` files, and it works.

```
$(C_OBJ_FILES)      :   $(C_SRCS)
    $(COMPILE_C_COMMAND)

$(CXX_OBJ_FILES)    :   $(CXX_SRCS)
    $(COMPILE_CXX_COMMAND)
```

However, this creates a new problem.  We have to use some different versions of Make, and one of them fails with the following error whenever there are no `.cpp` files:

> No targets on dependency line. Stop.

It references this line:  `$(CXX_OBJ_FILES) :   $(CXX_SRCS)`

Gnu make seems to have no problem with this situation, our other one does (OPUS Make).  Can anyone think of a workaround?

Comment: I'd personally recommend using cmake rather than make. It takes care of details such as this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, not an option here.

Comment: It's really not right to create a rule like `%.$(OBJ_EXT) : $(C_SRCS)`.  This tells make that each individual object file has every source file as a prerequisite.  It means that if you change any one source file, every object file will be rebuilt.  That's not what you want.

Comment: Agreed, I may find time to create a more precise rule in the future. I don't like when stuff is wrong but still works.  Currently, this works because all source files are copied to a new directory before each build (because it's built by CI), so the "change detection" mechanism of Make is irrelevant. Sadly, I think the more precise/correct Makefile will be more complicated. Primarily because we need the rule to deal with $(C_SRCS) being generated, and containing files from any number of sub-directories: path1/file1.c path2/file2.c.  If you have an elegant suggestion for that, would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [suffix rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html):

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall

OBJS = cobj1.o cobj2.o cppobj1.o

.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.cpp.o:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: I was really optimistic with this approach, and the suffix rules did seem to get the desired effect on GNU make, but I get an error with OPUS MAKE:   > Don't know how to make 'src/Action.o'. Stop.

Comment: Oh, I thought you had two different versions of GNU make. This syntax is probably GNU-specific.

Comment: Yes it seems so.  Still looking for an alternative make syntax that solves the problem.

Comment: Actually, it seems that this syntax should be supported in OPUS make, I will revisit the error: http://www.opussoftware.com/tutorial/TutMakefile.htm

Comment: Could not get it to work. Instead, i used a different extension for object files from C++ files, thereby removing the ambiguity between the targets.

Answer (score 0):

Added

```
CXX_OBJ_EXT           ?= obj
```

Replaced

```
CXX_OBJ_FILES         += $(CXX_SRCS:.$(CXX_EXT)=.$(OBJ_EXT))
CXX_OBJ_FILES         += $(CXX_SRCS:.$(CXX_EXT)=.$(CXX_OBJ_EXT))
```

Replaced

```
%.$(OBJ_EXT)          :   $(CXX_SRCS)
%.$(CXX_OBJ_EXT)      :   $(CXX_SRCS)
```